# How to import System.Web.WebPages string extension methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# console application and want to import the [StringExtension class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.stringextensions(v=vs.111).aspx) in my project, which provides useful helper methods like `IsInt()`, 'AsBool()`etc. I tried doing`using System.Web.WebPages` but C# cannot find it. This is all well if I do it inside ASP.NET MVC application, for example in a controller class file, the namespace is available. How can I import this namespace in a console application?

Comment: Does your project have a reference to `System.Web`?

Comment: Why not just use the [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) class methods?

Comment: You may like to use also: Int32.TryParse() and Boolean.TryParse().

Comment: It should be enough to install **Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages** nuget package and then required reference can be added.

Comment: @AndrewSilver can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @anemaria20 sure, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to install **Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages** nuget package and then required reference (using string) can be added.

Answer (score 0):

Just add System.Web.WebPages.dll in references of your project.